# in R try to plot two variables on y axis with different colours and also abline needed -cannot combine both

Tags: r

I am trying to plot two different variables on y axis vs. age category on x axis. I would like to have different colors for this. So far so good I used

`xyplot(PRR+EBGM ~AGEcateg |drug, 
    type="b",pch=17,lty=1,cex=1,
    col=c("lightblue","darkblue"),
    layout=c(3,1),
    aspect=1.5,
    main="PRR values stratified by age category for selected Drug Event      Combinations",
    xlab="Paediatric age category", 
    ylab="Proportional reporting ratio")`

However I understood xyplot does not have abline so I tried to make it via a function:

```
mypanel <- function(x, y, y0) {
panel.xyplot(x, y, pch=17,lty=1,cex=1, col=c("lightblue", "darkblue"))
panel.lines(x,y)
panel.abline(h=1,col="red",lty=2)
```

}

But I do not know how to make this function to plot lines with different colours, I just get different colours for the points but the line itself is the same ... 
This is what I get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvGPh.png)

Super thanks!
Lexie

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your dataframe might look something like the following:

```
x <- seq(1:5)
y1 <- runif(5)
y2 <- sample(1:100,5)
data <- data.frame(x,y1,y2)
```

And If you would like to plot y1 and y2 versus x, you can use `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(data) +
geom_line(aes(x, y1), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(x,y2), color = "green")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Shiva. And is also possible to add a abline withing ggplot2?

Comment: @Lexie yes of course. you can add it please looking in to the ggplot manual :) As I have not tried abline in ggplot yet :)